# How to close one of the datatable pane buttons when the others are opened?

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables, pane

I am using datatable by importing the link here. But I want the others to be closed when one of the pane buttons is clicked. I could not find such a plugin if it exists on the Datatable site.
I tried to add event handlers with javascript but I can't access the buttons. Returns Nodelist(0) length 0. How can I access the buttons with javascript?
Or is there another way to turn the buttons off? Thanks

https://datatables.net/extensions/searchpanes/examples/integration/buttons.html

Comment: Can you not just use the "Collapse All" and "Show All" buttons, which already exist in the demo you linked to?

Comment: Or you can open and close each pane individually. Don't these approaches cover what you are asking to do? Maybe I have misunderstood your question...

Comment: Yeah I can use Collapse All and Show All buttons but unlike the demo I added more buttons and they came one under the other. So when user opens one of them the buttons cover the other button. For this and some other reasons I really need that when one button opens, the other closes.

Comment: How can we recreate your issue? Can you provide a [mre]?